# Error in powershell when trying to download a link

Tags: powershell, vsphere

I have to do a powershell script that list all disks in a Vsphere environment, then extract the URL and download the files in those URL, I've tried different things and nothing seems to work.

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Web
$output = "C:\Users\home\Desktop"
$links = (Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri "https://vcenter.company/folder/VM1?dcPath=DATACENTER&dsName=datastore1").Links.Href
$links = $links -replace "/folder/", "https://vcenter.company/folder/"
$links = $links | Select-String -Pattern ".vmdk"
$links > test.txt

foreach ($row in $links)
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers $row
}
```

$headers are the credentials of the site.

test.txt is the list of the direct url's to download the file. Like this:
https://vcenter.company/folder/VM1/VM1-000001-sesparse.vmdk?dcPath=DATACENTER&dsName=datastore1

But got this error when I try to execute the foreach loop:

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert the """""URL"""""" value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo"
to type "System.Uri".

Edit 1: I'm just starting with Powershell so any help is well appreciated.

Comment: foreach ($row in $links)
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri [string]$row -Headers $headers 
}

Comment: the `Select-String` cmdlet does NOT output the matches, nor does it output the matching line. it outputs a matchinfo object. you need to extract the actual VALUE of the match.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the actual link with the ansible tag? Else can your please edit your question and remove it? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator Well, this script is uploaded to the Win Server via Ansible, but I understand you, removed, thanks.

Comment: @FletcherF1 Thanks, now I get the "Invoke-WebRequest : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.", kinda weird because the DNS works fine.

Comment: Did you check previously a $row before request in loop? is it a string? is it correct?